# What’s the term that summarizes when a rule that hasn’t been enforced in the past suddenly gets enforced without warning?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, when parents set a curfew but don’t punish you for breaking it for months on end, but then suddenly crack down on you for it. Please help! This has plagued me for years now trying to remember the term! Thanks!

Comment: You’ve already used the phrase I would use: cracking down. Can you clarify better why this doesn’t work and what exactly you’re looking for?

Comment: How about "selective enforcement"?

Comment: ... Yes, [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/crack-down) gives 'to start dealing with bad or illegal behavior in a more severe way' as the principal sense, with 'to take strong action to stop something' the secondary sense. As @Laurel says, a near perfect fit (which is better than one usually has to manage with).